# Return PostgreSQL UUID array as list with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, type-conversion, uuid, psycopg2

I have an SQL statement which contains a subquery embedded in an `ARRAY()` like so:

```
SELECT foo, ARRAY(SELECT x from y) AS bar ...
```

The query works fine, however in the psycopg2 results cursor the array is returned as a string (as in `"{1,2,3}"`), not a list.

My question is, what would be the best way to convert strings like these into python lists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works for me without the need for parsing:

```
import psycopg2

query = """
    select array(select * from (values (1), (2)) s);
"""

conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=cpn user=cpn')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
rs = cursor.fetchall()

for l in rs:
    print l[0]

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Result when executed:

```
$ python stackoverflow_select_array.py 
[1, 2]
```

### Update

You need to register the uuid type:

```
import psycopg2, psycopg2.extras

query = """
    select array(
        select *
        from (values
            ('A0EEBC99-9C0B-4EF8-BB6D-6BB9BD380A11'::uuid),
            ('A0EEBC99-9C0B-4EF8-BB6D-6BB9BD380A11'::uuid)
        )s
    );
"""

psycopg2.extras.register_uuid()

conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=cpn user=cpn')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
rs = cursor.fetchall()

for l in rs:
    print l[0]

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Result:

```
$ python stackoverflow_select_array.py 
[UUID('a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11'), UUID('a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11')]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I went back and played with the code some more, and you're right it does work but only for Integer and String column types. The column I'm retrieving in the array is actually of type UUID, and that still comes back as a string. Sorry, I over simplified my code when I originally posted, I didn't realise the column type would affect this.

Answer (score 0):

If every result cursor ARRAY is of the format `'{x,y,z}'`, then you can do this to strip the string of the braces and split it into a list by comma-delimiter:

```
>>> s = '{1,2,3}'
>>> s
'{1,2,3}'
>>> l = s.rstrip('}').lstrip('{').split(',')
>>> l
['1', '2', '3']
>>>
>>> s = '{1,2,3,a,b,c}'
>>> s
'{1,2,3,a,b,c}'
>>> l = s.rstrip('}').lstrip('{').split(',')
>>> l
['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this does work. If I can't find out why ARRAY() isn't working for UUID fields (see below), I'll go for this approach.

Comment: That's because UUID type was not supported in `psycopg2` python. But now, in new version of `psycopg2`, we can register this type using `psycopg2.extras.register_uuid()`. Another way would be to cast the uuid array to a text array. See my answer. @BenScott

Answer (score 0):

Another way of handling this is to explicitly tell postgres that you want text, then the default psycopg2 string parsing logic will kick in and you'll get a list:

```
db = psycopg2.connect('...')
curs = db.cursor()
curs.execute("""
    SELECT s.id, array_agg(s.kind::text)
        FROM (VALUES ('A', 'A0EEBC99-9C0B-AEF8-BB6D-6BB9BD380A11'::uuid),
                     ('A', 'A0EEBC99-9C0B-4EF8-BB6D-6BB9BD380A12'::uuid)) AS s (id, kind)
    GROUP BY s.id
""")
for row in curs:
    print "row: {}".format(row)
```

Results in:

```
row: (u'A', [u'a0eebc99-9c0b-aef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11', u'a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a12'])
```

and the query

```
curs.execute("""
    SELECT array(
        SELECT s.kind::text
        FROM (VALUES ('A0EEBC99-9C0B-AEF8-BB6D-6BB9BD380A11'::uuid),
                     ('A0EEBC99-9C0B-4EF8-BB6D-6BB9BD380A12'::uuid)) AS s (kind))
""")
for row in curs:
    print "row: {}".format(row)
```

results in:

```
row: ([u'a0eebc99-9c0b-aef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11', u'a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a12'],)
```

The trick is specifically attaching the `::text` to the fields that you care about.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

Convert the UUID array `uuid[]` to a text array `text[]`

```
select
    p.name,
    array(
        select _i.item_id
        from items _i
        where _i.owner_id = p.person_id
    )::text[] as item_ids
from persons p;
```

The from python code:

```
import psycopg2.extras
curs = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=extras.DictCursor)  # To get rows in dictionary
curs.execute(my_query)
rows = curs.fetchall()
print(dict(row[0]))
```

#### Output:

```
{
    "name": "Alex",
    "item_ids": [
        "db6c19a2-7627-4dff-a963-b90b6217cb11",
        "db6c19a2-7627-4dff-a963-b90b6217cb11"
    ]
}
```

## Solution 2

Register the UUID type so that the PostgreSQL `uuid` can be converted to python `uuid.UUID` (see [python UUID docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#example)) type.

```
import psycopg2.extras
psycopg2.extras.register_uuid()
```

After this, you can use the query **without needing to convert** to text array using `::text[]`.

```
select
    p.name,
    array(
        select _i.item_id
        from items _i
        where _i.owner_id = p.person_id
    ) as item_ids
from persons p;
```

The output in DictRow will be like:

```
{
    "name": "Alex",
    "item_ids": [
        UUID("db6c19a2-7627-4dff-a963-b90b6217cb11"),
        UUID("db6c19a2-7627-4dff-a963-b90b6217cb11")  # uuid.UUID data type
    ]
}
```