# in postgres select, return a column subquery as an array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions

(have done this before, but memory fades, as does goggle)

wish to get select from `users` with the `tag.tag_id`s for each user returned as an array.

```
select usr_id,
       name,
       (select t.tag_id from tags t where t.usr_id = u.usr_id) as tag_arr
from   users u;
```

with the idea embedded query `tag_arr` would be an array

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - yep. too many languages, too many years - thanks

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use the [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select
    usr_id, 
    name, 
    array_agg(tag_id) as tag_arr
from users
join tags using(usr_id)
group by usr_id, name
```

or an [array constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) from the results of a subquery:

```
select
    u.usr_id, 
    name, 
    array(
        select tag_id 
        from tags t 
        where t.usr_id = u.usr_id
        ) as tag_arr
from users u
```

The second option is a simple one-source query while the first one is more generic, especially convenient when you need more than one aggregate from a related table. Also, the first variant should be faster on larger tables.

Note, that for better performance the `usr_id` columns in both tables should be indexed. While typically `users.usr_id` is a primary key, sometimes one may forget that the index of referencing column is also useful.

Comment: Of those two options, can the first one using `array_agg()` have significantly better execution time? I presume it depends on the sizes of the data tables involved. In a real project I just compared the two queries with `explain analyze` and got execution times of `120ms` vs `10s` respectively. I'm not expert at db query plans, so any insight on how these two execute differently would be helpful.

Comment: @broc.seib - it depends on many factors such as the number of rows in both tables, the average number of tags per user, Postgres version, server and hardware configuration. For larger tables, the first query should be faster than the other. The difference in your case seems too large though. The reason may be the lack of index on `tags(usr_id)`, which would be useful for the first query as well.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `array` constructor of PostgreSQL:

```
select
    usr_id,
    name,
    array(select t.tag_id from tags t where t.usr_id = u.usr_id) as tag_arr
from users u;
```

#### Note:

If you're using `psycopg2` with python, then the result will be converted to a python `list` as well! (Although for `uuid[]` array, you will need to convert it to `text[]` array using `array(...)::text[]`, if you want to get IDs in python list). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797767/return-postgresql-uuid-array-as-list-with-psycopg2/69778225#69778225) for details.