# Using the group function to return an array of ID's as a value and the .group(:field) as the key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to group a large table by a foreign key in order to make some changes to those records.

What I would like to do is `group(:foreign_key_id)` and return the `ids` in this group. So I would get:
`{foreign_key_id => [array of ID's with this key], {foreign_key_id => [array of ID's with this key] }`

Maybe I should be mapping the (&:id) value, but this function sits behind a `where` so it's not *all* records of this foreign key that are returned.

My working code would be something like this:

`SubscriptionTag.where(subscription_id: @paper.subscriptions.map(&:id).group(:tag_id)`

This returns all unique tags used by my subset of subscriptions. Now I would like to also return the SubscriptionTag ids  along with each tag_id

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. What is your RDBMS ?

Comment: Hey @PavelMikhailyuk. I'm using Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453151/in-postgres-select-return-a-column-subquery-as-an-array), you can use `pluck` with `array_agg` and then `#to_h`:

```
Subscription.group(:tag_id).pluck(:tag_id, 'array_agg(id)').to_h
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for your help